# Arithmetic of Ramanujan's $\tau$-function

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

I'm planning to give a short and introductory talk about modular forms, and I'm going to say that modular forms' Fourier coefficients are *arithmetic*, which is certainly not a mathematically well-defined sentence but (at least for me) shows the importance of modular form in number theory. Three basic examples I'll introduce is the following:

- Eisenstein series
- Discriminant function
- Theta function

The Fourier coefficients of Eisenstein series are divisor power sum functions, and Fourier coefficients of  (power of) theta functions are related to the number of representing a given number as sum of squares. However, it is hard for me to explain arithmetic significance of $\tau$ function. Here's a list of facts that I know about $\tau(n)$:

- Multiplicative since $\Delta(z)$ is a Hecke eigenform
- $|\tau(p)| \leq 2 p^{11/2}$ (Ramanujan-Petersson conjecture, which has automorphic form version that is only known for a few cases)
- Can be expressed as combination of divisor sum functions, by using the identity between $\Delta(z)$ and Eisenstein series
- several congruences in wikipedia

and this list doesn't seem to be the *arithmetic heart* of the $\tau(n)$. Could anyone explain the arithmetic essence of $\tau(n)$?

Comment: A quick Google search turned up a recent article "Combinatorial interpretations of Ramanujan’s tau function" by Garvan and Schlosser in Oct 2018, Discrete Mathematics, 2832-2840.